# Removing redundant data from large file

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a log file which has single strings on each line.  I am trying to remove duplicate data from the file and save the file out as a new file.  I had first thought of reading data into a HashSet and then saving the contents of the hashset out, however I get an "OutOfMemory" exception when attempting to do this (on the line that adds the string to the hashset).

There are around 32,000,000 lines in the files.  It's not practical to re-read the entire file for each comparison.

Any ideas?  My other thought was to output the entire contents into a SQLite database and selecting DISTINCT values, but I'm not sure that'd work either with that many values.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Can you use `File.ReadAllLines` without an OutOfMemoryException? I assume you're running it on a 32 bit system.

Comment: I am running it on 64 bit system, and I haven't tried ReadAllLines.  I did want to try and know how many items were eliminated so I was using a streamreader to read each line and add it to the hashset.  I am testing the result of the .Add() method to see if it returns false to count the number of items that are redundant.  I'd like to keep this feature if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to think about - is high memory consumption is a problem?

If your application will always run on server with a lot of RAM available, or in any other case you know you'll have enough memory, you can do a lot of things you can't do if your application will run in a low-memory environment, or in an unknown environment. If memory isn't the problem, then make sure your application is running as a 64-bit application (of course, on 64-bit OS), otherwise you'll be limited to 2GB memory (4GB, if you'll use LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag). I guess then in this case this is your problem, and all you've got to do is change it - and it'll work great (assuming you have enough memory).

If memory is a problem, and you need not to use too much memory, you can as you suggested add all the data to database (i'm more familiar with databases like SQL Server, but i guess SQLite will do), make sure you have the right index on the column, and then select distinct value.

Another option, is to read the file as a stream, line by line, for each line calculate hash, and save the line into other file, and keep the hash in the memory. if the hash already exists, then moving to the next line (and, if you wish, adding to a counter of number of lines removed). in that case, you'll save less data in the memory (only hash for not  duplicated items).

Best of luck.

Comment: I recompiled this into 64bit.  This allowed me to have enough room in memory.  The file stream/hash is also a good idea!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use an array to intialize the `HashSet`. I assume that the doubling algorithm of `HashSet` is the reason for the `OutOfMemoryException`.

```
var uniqueLines = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\BigFile.log"));
```

**Edit**:

> I am testing the result of the .Add() method to see if it
>   returns false to count the number of items that are redundant. I'd
>   like to keep this feature if possible.

Then you should try to initilize the `HashSet` with the correct(maximum) size of the file's lines:

```
int lineCount = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
List<string> fooList = new List<String>(lineCount);
var uniqueLines = new HashSet<string>(fooList);
fooList.Clear();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    uniqueLines.Add(line);
```

Comment: Please seem my comment above.  I'd like to be able to know how many items were removed, and I think using this method won't allow that.

Comment: @rune711: Edited my answer to provide a different way to save memory.

Answer (score 1):

I took a similar approach to Tim using HashSet. I did add manual line counting and comparison.

I read the setup log from my windows 8 install which was 58MB in size at 312248 lines and ran it in LinqPad in .993 seconds.

```
var temp=new List<string>(10000);
var uniqueHash=new HashSet<int>();
int lineCount=0;
int uniqueLineCount=0;

using(var fs=new FileStream(@"C:\windows\panther\setupact.log",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
    using(var sr=new StreamReader(fs,true)){
        while(!sr.EndOfStream){
        lineCount++;
        var line=sr.ReadLine();
        var key=line.GetHashCode();
            if(!uniqueHash.Contains(key) ){
                uniqueHash.Add(key);
                temp.Add(line);
                uniqueLineCount++;
                    if(temp.Count()>10000){
                        File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\temp\output.txt",temp);
                        temp.Clear();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
Console.WriteLine("Total Lines:"+lineCount.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Lines Removed:"+ (lineCount-uniqueLineCount).ToString());
```

[image: perf in linqpad]